# Dual boot Linux/Mac OS X with native file support

Tags: dual-boot, macbook, macosx

What I want to do is dual boot Mac OS X and Linux on my MacBook and have access to files on both systems with no problems (if that's even possible).  I have already got dual boot but I cannot write/access certain files on my MacBook drive (not to mention any HFS+ drives) and I cannot even mount the Linux boot drive while on Mac OS X, just doesn't show up anywhere.

I think I have already read about this somewhere, though I can't remember exactly where.  Was something to do with switching usertype or something along those lines on MacOSX.

Answer (score 0):

This looks the closest to what I was looking for, found it just reading up on other things, figured if anybody else has similar concerns it would help them out: [A Comprehensive Guide to Sharing Your Data Across Multi-Booting Windows, Mac, and Linux PCs](http://lifehacker.com/5702815/the-complete-guide-to-sharing-your-data-across-multiple-operating-systems)